# power sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How do I calculate the radius of the power sum of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{n^2}$$

having a little trouble with the second power(of $x$)

thank you

Comment: Write the sum as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ to apply the usual radius of convergence test.

Comment: Maybe fool around with a few $x$. For the formal calculation, have you tried the natural tools, Root Test, or Ratio Test? If so, what issue arose? Each works nicely. Root Rest is marginally less trouble.

Comment: You can use them. Just include the $x$ stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the $n$th root of the $n$th term is $2x^n,$ which is asymptotically smaller than $1$ when $x^n$ is eventually smaller than $1/2.$ This is true when $|x| < 1,$ and not otherwise.